# Macbook Air: Model of 2013 or 2014?

Tags: macbook-pro

New apple user here,

I found this Macbook Air model:
http://www.ispot.ma/index.php/mac-15/macbook-air/macbook-air-md760.html

When I did a search about the Serial Order (**MD760F/A**), I couldn't find it!

**My Question:**
**How to identify this model?**

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have here is a model number, not a "Serial Oder".

You can look up Mac model numbers here, for example:
http://www.everymac.com/ultimate-mac-lookup/?search_keywords=MD760F%2FA